# Task duration does not represent resource usage

Tags: duration, ms-project

In Microsoft Project 2016 if you:

1. Set the project options > schedule > hours per day to 10 hours and 50 hours a week.
2. Create a task with one resource in it and then add 10 hours a day for 10 consequative days the tasks duration is 8 days and not 10 days!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the default calendar Standard. Change times for each day from 8 to 12 1 to 5 
to 
8 to 1 and 2 to 7. 
Then it will level resources out at 10 hours per day and then 100hours will be 10 hours for 10 days with a task duration of 10 days.